# Calling .getTimeStamp on objectID

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I've called the .getTimeStamp method on an _id coming from mongodb and it outputs as follows

```
<td><%= items[i]._id.getTimestamp() %></td>

Fri Apr 24 2015 15:28:34 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

Can I format the output to just display the first three params? I thought I may be able to format it by passing parameters but can't find anything online.

Comment: I'm not sure what your ultimate goal is here, but `getTimestamp().toDateString()` would get you just the date component, but including the year.

Comment: Thanks JohnnyHK but Jason's answer was the perfect fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation states [`.getTimeStamp`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/) returns the timestamp portion of the `ObjectId` as a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. So you can use any of the methods available to a `Date` object but custom formatting is not one of them. You could use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) but that might be overkill here. Alternatively you could get the ISO date string and then split on the spaces for the first three items and join them.

`(items[i]._id.getTimestamp()).toDateString().split(' ', 3).join(' ')`

Comment: Thank you, I was just considering splitting the string but thought there might have been an easier way. Works a treat.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If this answered your question don't forget to mark it as accepted so other people won't assume you are still looking for an answer. :)